# AWS CodePipeline deploying to ECS is always stuck at in progress state

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-codepipeline

I am trying to deploy the simple Node JS/ Express app to AWS ECS using CodePipeline. But the pipeline is stuck at the deploy stage.

I first created an ECR repository and pushed my image into the repository. You can see my Dockerfile [in this repo](https://github.com/waiyanhein/aws-ecs-express-app). It's a simple Express JS application.

I can successfully build and push the image to ECR repository and I got an image URI which looks like this.

`1111111111.dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/node-api:latest`

Using that image URI, I created the necessary ECS resources using the CloudFormation. This is the CloudFormation template I am using.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Description: My Node API application infra

Parameters:
  AppPort:
    Default: 3000
    Type: String
    Description: The port Node JS app is running on

  VpcCidr:
    Default: 10.0.0.0/16
    Type: String
    Description: The CIDR block for the VPC

  ImageUri:
    Default: 1111111111.dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/node-api:latest
    Type: String
    Description: ECS Image URI

  ContainerFamilyService:
    Default: node-api
    Type: String
    Description: ECS Container Name

Resources:
  # ########### network layer starts here ###########
  Vpc:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: !Ref VpcCidr
      EnableDnsHostnames: true
      EnableDnsSupport: true
      InstanceTenancy: default
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-vpc

  InternetGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway
    Properties:
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-igw

  VpcGatewayAttachment:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      InternetGatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc

  EIP1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::EIP
    Properties:
      Domain: vpc
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-eip-1

  EIP2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::EIP
    Properties:
      Domain: vpc
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-eip-2

  NatGateway1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::NatGateway
    Properties:
      AllocationId: !GetAtt EIP1.AllocationId
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet1
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-nat-gateway-1

  NatGateway2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::NatGateway
    Properties:
      AllocationId: !GetAtt EIP2.AllocationId
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet2
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-nat-gateway-2

  PublicSubnet1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 0, !GetAZs '' ]
      CidrBlock: !Select [ 0, !Cidr [ !GetAtt Vpc.CidrBlock, 4, 14 ] ]
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-public-subnet-1

  PublicSubnet2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 1, !GetAZs '' ]
      CidrBlock: !Select [ 1, !Cidr [ !GetAtt Vpc.CidrBlock, 4, 14 ] ]
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-public-subnet-2

  PrivateSubnet1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 0, !GetAZs '' ]
      CidrBlock: !Select [ 2, !Cidr [ !GetAtt Vpc.CidrBlock, 4, 14 ] ]
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: false
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-private-subnet-1

  PrivateSubnet2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 1, !GetAZs '' ]
      CidrBlock: !Select [ 3, !Cidr [ !GetAtt Vpc.CidrBlock, 4, 14 ] ]
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: false
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-private-subnet-2

  PublicRouteTable1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-public-rt-1

  PublicRouteTable2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-public-rt-2

  PrivateRouteTable1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-private-rt-1

  PrivateRouteTable2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-private-rt-2

  PublicRouteTable1Association:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable1
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet1

  PublicRouteTable2Association:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable2
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet2

  PrivateRouteTable1Association:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateRouteTable1
      SubnetId: !Ref PrivateSubnet1

  PrivateRouteTable2Association:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateRouteTable2
      SubnetId: !Ref PrivateSubnet2

  Public1DefaultRoute:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    DependsOn: VpcGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable1
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      GatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway

  Public2DefaultRoute:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    DependsOn: VpcGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable2
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      GatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway

  Private1DefaultRoute:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    DependsOn: VpcGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateRouteTable1
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      NatGatewayId: !Ref NatGateway1

  Private2DefaultRoute:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    DependsOn: VpcGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateRouteTable2
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      NatGatewayId: !Ref NatGateway2
  # ########### network layer ends here ###########

  # ########### ALB starts here ###########
  NodeApiAlbSg:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Security group for node api alb
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 80
          ToPort: 80
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 80
          ToPort: 80
          CidrIpv6: ::/0
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-alb-sg

  NodeApiAlb:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer
    Properties:
      Name: node-api-alb
      Subnets:
        - !Ref PublicSubnet1
        - !Ref PublicSubnet2
      SecurityGroups:
        - !GetAtt NodeApiAlbSg.GroupId
      Type: application
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-alb

  NodeApiFargateTargetGroup:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
    Properties:
      Name: NodeApiTargetGroup
      Port: !Ref AppPort
      Protocol: HTTP
      TargetType: ip
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc
      HealthCheckPath: /health
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-fargate-target-group

  AlbListener:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
    Properties:
      LoadBalancerArn: !Ref NodeApiAlb
      Port: 80
      Protocol: HTTP
      DefaultActions:
        - Type: forward
          TargetGroupArn: !Ref NodeApiFargateTargetGroup
  # ########### ALB ends here ###########

  # ########### ECS starts here ###########
  NodeApiEcsTaskSg:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupName: node-api-ecs-task-sg
      GroupDescription: Security group for node-api-ecs-task
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 80
          ToPort: 80
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: !Ref AppPort
          ToPort: !Ref AppPort
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 80
          ToPort: 80
          CidrIpv6: ::/0
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: !Ref AppPort
          ToPort: !Ref AppPort
          CidrIpv6: ::/0
        # We can simplify the inbound rules like this
#        - IpProtocol: -1
#          SourceSecurityGroupId: !GetAtt NodeApiAlbSg.GroupId
#          Description: Allow all traffic from ALB
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-ecs-task-sg

  NodeApiTaskExecutionRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: nodeApiEcsTaskExecutionRole
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2008-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-ecs-task-execution-role

  NodeApiTaskDefinition:
    Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
    DependsOn: NodeApiAlb
    Properties:
      RequiresCompatibilities:
        - FARGATE
      ExecutionRoleArn: !Ref NodeApiTaskExecutionRole
      Cpu: 1 vCPU
      Memory: 3 GB
      Family: !Ref ContainerFamilyService
      NetworkMode: awsvpc
      ContainerDefinitions:
        - Name: !Ref ContainerFamilyService
          Image: !Ref ImageUri
          PortMappings:
            - ContainerPort: !Ref AppPort
              HostPort: !Ref AppPort
              Protocol: tcp
#            LogConfiguration:
#                LogDriver: awslogs
#                Options:
#                awslogs-group: /ecs/node-api
#                awslogs-region: ap-southeast-2
#                awslogs-stream-prefix: ecs
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-ecs-task-definition

  NodeApiEcsCluster:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Cluster
    DependsOn: NodeApiTaskDefinition
    Properties:
      ClusterName: node-api-ecs-cluster
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-ecs-cluster

  NodeApiEcsService:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Service
    DependsOn: AlbListener
    Properties:
      LaunchType: FARGATE
      Cluster: !Ref NodeApiEcsCluster
      DesiredCount: 2
      ServiceName: !Ref ContainerFamilyService
      TaskDefinition: !Ref NodeApiTaskDefinition
      DeploymentConfiguration:
        MaximumPercent: 100
        MinimumHealthyPercent: 50
      NetworkConfiguration:
        AwsvpcConfiguration:
          AssignPublicIp: ENABLED
          SecurityGroups:
            - !GetAtt NodeApiEcsTaskSg.GroupId
          Subnets:
            - !Ref PrivateSubnet1
            - !Ref PrivateSubnet2
      LoadBalancers:
        - ContainerName: node-api
          ContainerPort: !Ref AppPort
          TargetGroupArn: !Ref NodeApiFargateTargetGroup
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-ecs-service
  # ########### ECS ends here ###########
```

I could create the CloudFormation stack without any issue and my app is now up and running. I can access it opening the Load Balancer's DNS in the browser.

Up until now, everything is working as expected. Then I started building the CodePipeline to automate the deployment process. What I want is that, when I pushed the new code to the repository (CodeCommit), I want to pipeline to build and push the image to the ECR repository and deploy the app to the ECS using the latest image.

First I created a CodeCommit repository and pushed my code (same code in my Github repo). As you can see, there's also a buildspec.yml file in my repo. I pushed all of files to my new CodeCommit repo.

Then I started building the CodePipeline.

For Source provider, I used the CodeCommit repo I created and main branch.

For Build, I created a new CodeBuild project. I let the AWS create a role for my CodeBuild. Later I attached, `AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryPowerUser` managed policy to the codebuild's IAM role.

For the Deploy stage, I selected Amazon ECS, and I selected my ECS cluster and ECS service that was created using the CloudFormation. For the filename, I set `imagedefinitions.json`.

When I run the pipeline, the Source and Build stages were run successfully. But the pipeline is stuck at the Deploy stage and it never ends. The deploy stage is always in progress state. What is wrong with my configuration and how can I fix it?

Comment: It's possible the ECS container is "flapping". Within ECS, can you check the task for your service? For example, navigate to ECS > Clusters > Your Service > Tasks > Your Task > Logs (I think).

I see this behavior sometimes when I've forgotten to properly setup permissions, secrets configuration, and other little mistakes. Looking around in the UI for ECS might give you some clues. To check the "flapping" issue, goto to the Tasks tab on the Service page. For the "Tasks" table, change the filter from "Running Tasks" to "All Tasks". Are you seeing the tasks being created and deprovisioned?

Comment: @Gregg, I think when the pipeline is doing the deployment, I can see a task turned to Deactivating and Stopped while another task continue running. Not sure if that is the issue. But I don't see any task being created. What is flapping and how can I fix it?

Comment: When the pipeline is not doing the deployment, I saw there were two tasks running.

Comment: Also in the Deployments tab, I could see an in progress deployment which does not seem to end.

Comment: Watch those tasks for a few minutes. Are they cycling through? Does it look like they are being created and destroyed repeatedly? For each task, does the "Started At" column show the tasks as being created several minutes ago?

Comment: Another thought is the health check. Have you configured the health check yet? If so, you'll need to add a route in your Node Express app to return a 200 status code. ECS might be shutting them down because the health check is failing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254865/discussion-between-gregg-and-wai-yan-hein).